# My navbar and footer not occupying full width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar and footer not occupying full width. I tried changing CSS properties of footer and navbar yet the space is not being filled. I also tried positioning it as left 0 right 0.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="title" class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container navigation_bar">
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-dark brand_logo"></a>
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Explore
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What version of BS?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and provide  a complete HTML snippet. Your HTML structure is faulty and it's not clear why you have a row outside a container.

Answer (score -1):

For a proper answer i need to see your CSS code as well but by guessing, i can recommend you to set margins 0, and width to 100%, if it is bootstrap add w-100,d-flex,m-0 classes to your div.

```
.yourDivYouWantFullWidth{
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: This type of custom CSS for basic sizing is almost never needed with Bootstrap.